# Android AlarmManager using default alarm tone

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager

I am trying to use Alarm Manager in Android. What I want is when the Alarm goes off it should play the default alarm clock tone that I have set for the android clock. I used the following code

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
    mp.start();
```

However, I get following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.user.alarmmanager.MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at 

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.user.alarmmanager.MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(MyBroadcastReceiver.java:25)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys if ALARM tone is none there is possible of crash.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `MediaPlayer.create()` is returning `null`, indicating it had creation problems.  This is most likely because you're trying to create it in the context of a `BroadcastReceiver` which is a transient object and the `Context` object provided to your `onReceive()` method is a reduced functionality `Context`.  Receivers cannot block or do any type of heavy operation.  You should have your `BroadcastReceiver` start/message a `Service` running in your app to do the actual playback.

Comment: I tried using an mp3 file in my R.raw folder and used it instead of uri. It was running properly. But not when I use uri. And just for information the uri contains the alarm path in contentprovider form. Could that be some issue?

Comment: Yes, most likely.  `BroadcastReceiver`s are intended to be very short, when you create a `MediaPlayer` it is expected that you will retain it for a while so it can be controlled, etc.  When using a Uri it will use a `ContentResolver` to access the media/content, which can cause blocking calls and other things which should not be done from a `BroadcastReceiver`.  So the `MediaPlayer.create()` is likely failing behind the scenes due to this.

Comment: Ok.. So I made this change where I replaced all the MediaPlayer and Uri stuff with just a ringtone and called `ringtone.play()` and it is working. Just don't get why is it that it plays notification and ringtone tones but not alarm_alert. Could that be device specific?

Comment: Because ringtones are handled by the `RingtoneManager` which is running in a different process context and playing media on your behalf.  `MediaPlayer` communicates with the media server to playback your audio, but it controls the state and possibly the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

i amn't sure but .. try making an instance of MediaPlayer and then use (setDataSource) instead